# Use port forwarding to access several computers via one public IP address

Tags: firewall, rdp, juniper, ssg5

I am trying to set up remote desktop access to several computers. I created the following custom service:

[image]

I then added the following VIP entries against the untrusted interface:

[image]

I then created the following policy from untrust to trust:

[image]

However, I am unable to connect to the computers. What am I doing wrong? Did I miss a step?

Comment: RDP is port 3389, not port 3899.

Comment: Damn, is that all I did wrong, lol.  So you see anything else that may be an issue?

Comment: I have no idea if anything else might be amiss. I just wanted to point out that RDP is port 3389. Hopefully that's all it takes to get it working.

Comment: Wow, well that is exactly what is was.  Thanks for the help.  I can't believe I missed that small detail.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a misconfiguration. RDP is port 3389, not port 3899.